# how to check html tags and the replace content between those tags?

Tags: php, javascript

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/8/

Also I need to check `<li>` tag and `<h3>` tags.

Is it possible to check other words into those tags like `<a onclick="word_desc(23); classChange(1, 1);" id="txtid1" class="sel25">user key</a>` - here I want to replace only "user key", but when I put "a" to replace all "a" words including `<a>` tag and other words inside  tags are replaced. How to solve this?

Comment: what do you want to do ? replace <a>user key</a> with <a> <span style="background-color:#FFFF00">user</span></a> or just with this <span style="background-color:#FFFF00">user</span>. Can you expalin more? Give input and out put please.

Comment: @erimerturk I have a string like "<a onclick="word_desc(24); classChange(1, 1);" id="txtid1" class="sel25">User Key</a>" . here I just want to replace/ highlight that "user key" Like <span style="background-color:#FFFF00">user</span>

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that to do this with regexes you'll need a ridiculously complex regex to ignore occurrences that appear within tags.  Instead, you can convert the string to an HTML DOM tree and only perform the highlighting on text nodes.

Now, you can't just replace a text node's nodeValue with HTML, it won't work.  You'll need to modify the nodeValue, and insert new nodes where required.  This may sound confusing, so I've jsFiddled it for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/29/

Answer (score 0):

i hope you need something like this. Because i couldnt understand your problem fully. So check this and addd comment then i can fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/28/

Comment: the problem is when I split the string into array first time it replace **<span style="background-color:#FFFF00"></span>** tag and second time when it get again "a" it replace "a" of <sp **a** n style="b **a** ckground-color:#FFFF00"></span>. so proper result is not displayed. here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/zEXrq/30/